# Matrix : get value from given matrix

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays

It's possible to print a matrix values as per below image

[image: The Matrix]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Try it and come back with your efforts :-)

Comment: Share your code if you have tried and it's not working.

Comment: I don't have any code, working on it.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the problem can be solved with the following helper function which calculates the indices of the next entry. The syntax is C#, but should work similar in Java, where `m` and `n` are supposed to be the respective matrix dimensions. The idea is to check whether the desired main direction is down-left or up-right; if the edge of the matrix is reached, which has to be checked beforehand, this is modified to right and down, respectively. The implementation assumes zero-based indexing of the rows and columns.

```
public struct Cell
{
    public int Row;
    public int Col;
}

public static Cell GetNext(Cell iCell)
{
    Cell Result;
    if (( iCell.Row + iCell.Col ) % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (iCell.Col == n - 1)
            Result = new Cell { Row = iCell.Row + 1, Col = n - 1 };
        else if (iCell.Row == 0)                    
            Result = new Cell { Row = 0, Col = iCell.Col + 1 };
        else
            Result = new Cell { Row = iCell.Row - 1, Col = iCell.Col + 1 };
    }
    else
    {
        if (iCell.Row == m - 1)
            Result = new Cell { Row = m - 1, Col = iCell.Col + 1 };
        else if (iCell.Col == 0)
            Result = new Cell { Row = iCell.Row + 1, Col = 0 };
        else
            Result = new Cell { Row = iCell.Row + 1, Col = iCell.Col - 1 };
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like @Codor's approach more. I thought I would throw this Java function in the mix too.

*[Note: I have not compiled or run this. But, I think it should work (mostly). Let me know. :)]*

```
public static int[] getTraversedArray(int[][] arr) {
     if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) 
        return null;

    # matrix need not be `nxn`
    int l = arr.length - 1, w = arr[0].length - 1;

    # all indices need to be visited
    int[] out = new int[(l + 1) * (w + 1)];

    int indx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= l + w; i++) {
        # "even" index
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            for (int x = i; x >= 0; x--) {
                # if it is a "valid index", set the value
                # in the output array
                if ((x <= l) && (i - x <= w)) {
                    out[indx] = arr[x][i - x];
                    indx++;
                }
            }
        } 
        # "odd" index
        else {
            for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
                # if it is a "valid index", set the value
                # in the output array
                if ((x <= l) && (i - x <= w)) {
                    out[indx] = arr[x][i - x];
                    indx++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```